# ¿Cómo completar las filas faltantes en una tabla (A) de otra tabla (B) en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy montando un aula virtual en PHP y MySQL. Esta aula consta de **cursos** y cada curso contiene diferentes **temas o módulos**. El alumno ha de examinarse de cada módulo y, finalmente, se hace un resumen (pizarra de evaluaciones) para saber si el alumno ha superado el curso o no.

Dicho esto, tengo una tabla en la que almaceno las evaluaciones de cada alumno, en la que guardo inscripcion_id (alumno), modulo_id, fecha_examen, numero_aciertos y convocatoria.

SQL Fiddle --> [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6369/1/0)

Mediante unas reglas previamente establecidas que me dicen si un alumno ha superado un módulo o no, obtengo el siguiente conjunto de datos:

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
| inscripcion_id | modulo_id |        fecha        | aciertos | ultima_convocatoria | estado |     ev     |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
|            890 |         1 | 2018-01-24 22:26:09 |        8 |                   2 |      1 | aprobado   |
|            890 |         2 | 2018-01-24 22:36:58 |        3 |                   3 |      0 | suspendido |
|            890 |         5 | 2018-01-24 22:38:50 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            890 |         6 | 2018-01-24 22:44:20 |        7 |                   3 |      0 | suspendido |
|            891 |         1 | 2018-01-25 09:24:42 |        8 |                   1 |      1 | aprobado   |
|            891 |         2 | 2018-01-25 10:01:55 |        4 |                   8 |      0 | suspendido |
|            891 |         4 | 2018-01-25 10:51:49 |        5 |                   3 |      1 | suspendido |
|            891 |         5 | 2018-01-25 10:23:45 |        9 |                   1 |      1 | aprobado   |
|            891 |         6 | 2018-01-25 11:21:20 |        7 |                   3 |      0 | suspendido |
|            896 |         1 | 2018-01-25 11:55:48 |        1 |                   1 |      1 | suspendido |
|            898 |         1 | 2018-01-25 14:01:51 |        6 |                   1 |      1 | suspendido |
|            907 |         1 | 2018-03-25 16:06:18 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         2 | 2018-03-25 16:07:34 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         3 | 2018-03-25 16:09:04 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         4 | 2018-03-25 16:08:13 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         5 | 2018-03-25 16:10:37 |        2 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         6 | 2018-03-25 16:08:44 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
```

Estos datos los obtengo mediante la siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT  e1.inscripcion_id,
        e1.modulo_id,
        e1.fecha,
        e1.aciertos,
        e1.convocatoria AS ultima_convocatoria,
        e1.estado,
        if  (
                ( e1.modulo_id in (SELECT modulo.modulo_id FROM modulo WHERE modulo.curso_id = 1 AND modulo.categoria_id = 1)
                    AND e1.aciertos <= 7 )
                OR ( e1.modulo_id = (SELECT modulo.modulo_id FROM modulo WHERE modulo.curso_id = 1 AND modulo.categoria_id = 2)
                    AND e1.aciertos <= 11 ),
                "suspendido",
                "aprobado"
        ) AS ev
FROM    (
            SELECT  inscripcion_id,
                    modulo_id,
                    MAX(convocatoria) AS max_convocatoria
            FROM `evaluacion`
            GROUP BY    inscripcion_id,
                        modulo_id
            ORDER BY    `inscripcion_id` ASC,
                        `modulo_id` ASC,
                        `convocatoria` ASC
) AS e2
INNER JOIN evaluacion AS e1
    ON e1.inscripcion_id = e2.inscripcion_id
    AND e1.modulo_id = e2.modulo_id
    AND e1.convocatoria = e2.max_convocatoria
```

**Como podéis ver, el alumno 890, ha realizado los módulos 1, 2, 5 y 6. Lo que yo quiero conseguir es que los módulos que aún están pendientes, también me salgan como resultado en el conjunto de datos anterior. Lo ejemplicfico:**

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
| inscripcion_id | modulo_id |        fecha        | aciertos | ultima_convocatoria | estado |     ev     |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
|            890 |         1 | 2018-01-24 22:26:09 | 8        | 2                   | 1      | aprobado   |
|            890 |         2 | 2018-01-24 22:36:58 | 3        | 3                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            890 |         3 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            890 |         4 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            890 |         5 | 2018-01-24 22:38:50 | 3        | 1                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            890 |         6 | 2018-01-24 22:44:20 | 7        | 3                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            891 |         1 | 2018-01-25 09:24:42 | 8        | 1                   | 1      | aprobado   |
|            891 |         2 | 2018-01-25 10:01:55 | 4        | 8                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            891 |         3 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            891 |         4 | 2018-01-25 10:51:49 | 5        | 3                   | 1      | suspendido |
|            891 |         5 | 2018-01-25 10:23:45 | 9        | 1                   | 1      | aprobado   |
|            891 |         6 | 2018-01-25 11:21:20 | 7        | 3                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            896 |         1 | 2018-01-25 11:55:48 | 1        | 1                   | 1      | suspendido |
|            896 |         2 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         3 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         4 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         5 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         6 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            ... |           |                     |          |                     |        |            |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
```

El resultado es que se han añadido los módulos que el alumno no ha realizado aún, con el nuevo valor "pendiente" para la columna **ev**.

No tengo ni idea de como hacer esto... lo he intentado, he buscado por todo internet y nada :(

**¿Cuál es el objetivo final?** Lo que quiero es obtener un listado final con todos aquellos alumnos que tienen el curso pendiente (es decir, que tienen **algún** módulo pendiente), para hacerles llegar un email de recordatorio de que han de realizar los módulos que les quedan pendientes. A los que han aprobado o suspendido, no se les hará llegar ningún email.

Me podéis ayudar?

SQL Fiddle --> [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6369/1/0)

**MUCHAS GRACIAS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debo aceptar que quede un poco enganchado con la pregunta dado que parece una solución fácil de JOINS, pero no es así

Sin embargo aunque se pudo resolver, me parece que el número de llamadas son muchas, quizá aun se pueda simplificar la consulta, pero por el momento funciona

```
SELECT ins_num, modulo_num, fecha, aciertos, convocatoria,
  if  (
    ( m1.modulo_num in (SELECT modulo.modulo_id FROM modulo WHERE modulo.curso_id = 1 AND modulo.categoria_id = 1)
    AND evaluacion.aciertos <= 7 )
    OR ( m1.modulo_num = (SELECT modulo.modulo_id FROM modulo WHERE modulo.curso_id = 1 AND modulo.categoria_id = 2)
    AND evaluacion.aciertos <= 11 ),
    "suspendido",
    if(aciertos IS NULL, "pendiente", "aprobado")
  ) AS ev
FROM 
   (SELECT  
      evaluacion.inscripcion_id AS ins_num,
      modulo.modulo_id AS modulo_num,
      (SELECT 
        MAX(convocatoria) 
        FROM evaluacion 
        WHERE modulo_id = modulo_num AND inscripcion_id = ins_num
      ) AS max_eval
   FROM modulo 
   LEFT JOIN evaluacion ON 1 = 1
   GROUP BY inscripcion_id, modulo.modulo_id
   ORDER BY ins_num, modulo_num
   ) AS m1
LEFT JOIN evaluacion ON 
   m1.max_eval = evaluacion.convocatoria AND
   m1.ins_num = evaluacion.inscripcion_id AND
   m1.modulo_num = evaluacion.modulo_id
ORDER BY ins_num, modulo_num;
```

Comment: eres un crack! muchas gracias por la solución! funciona a las mil maravillas!! Si te quedaste enganchado, tengo más dudas que resolver!! jajajaja, yo te la lanzo, a ver si cuela ;) Una vez obtienes el resultado con tu query, como hago para agrupar los resultados por 'inscripcion_id', teniendo en cuenta que quiero analizar el campo 'ev' y si hay 5 o más módulos aprobados, entonces el curso queda _aprobado_, si alguno de los 6 módulos está pendiente, la nota final queda como _pendiente_, y, finalmente, si tiene 2 o más módulos suspendidos, la nota final queda como _suspendido_...